# SAS: assigning variables based on another variable

Tags: select, if-statement, sas

I am trying to learn SAS. I see the following code in one of the programs:

```
data _null_;
    set Rates;
    IF attained_age = '<60'   then call symput('U_60_Alpha',count);
    IF attained_age = '<60'   then call symput('U_60_Beta',exposure);
    IF attained_age = '60-64' then call symput('U_60_64_Alpha',count);
    IF attained_age = '60-64' then call symput('U_60_64_Beta',exposure);
    IF attained_age = '65-69' then call symput('U_65_69_Alpha',count);
    IF attained_age = '65-69' then call symput('U_65_69_Beta',exposure);
run;
```

Would a better way to write this be something like this?

```
data _null_;
    set Rates;
    select (attained_age);
        when('<60');
          do;
             call symput('U_60_Alpha',count);
             call symput('U_60_Beta',exposure);
          end;
        when('60-64');
          do;
             call symput('U_60_64_Alpha',count);
             call symput('U_60_64_Beta',exposure);
          end;
        when('65-69');
          do;
             call symput('U_65_69_Alpha',count);
             call symput('U_65_69_Beta',exposure);
          end;
    end;
run;
```

Not sure if this is better or worse than the previous block - certainly takes more vertical space, but likely runs faster (much less comparisons needed). Are there other pros/cons? Which one would be preferable from your point of view?

Comment: You lost the `CALL` portion of the call symput.

Comment: @Reeza fixed thank you

Comment: You need to remove the semicolons between each `when('...')` and the following `do;`, and I would also recommend adding an `otherwise` block before the final closing `end` to prevent any other values of `attained_age` from halting your data step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second appears more efficient - if it's valid SAS code. I'm not used to seeing a do just like that and don't want to test right now.

Your variable appears to be a portion of the variable name in call symput. I would create a prefix and use that in my `call symput` code instead. I think this is easier to maintain and read.

```
if attained_age='<60' then prefix='U_60';
else if attained_age='60-64' then prefix='U_60_64';
else if attained_age='65-69' then prefix='U_65_69';

call symput(prefix||"_Alpha", count);
call symput(prefix||"_Beta", exposure);
```

Another method is to define a format that applies the prefix:

```
proc format;
value $ prefix
'<60' = 'U_60'
'60-65' = 'U_60_65'
'65-69' = 'U_65-69'
;
run;
```

Then in your data step:

```
call symput(put(attained_age, $prefix.)||"_Alpha", count);
call symput(put(attained_age, $prefix.)||"_Beta", exposure);
```

None of these will have 'significant' speed advantages unless you have large data sets - my guess is in the tens of millions.

Comment: So would this be better then:

select (attained_age);
    when ('<60'); prefix = 'U_60';
    when ('60-64'); prefix = 'U_60_64';
    when ('65-69'); prefix = 'U_65_69';
end;
    
call symput(prefix||"_Alpha", count);
call symput(prefix||"_Beta", exposure)

Comment: Are you concerned about performance or best practice? If performance I would suggest using a format instead. Technically a SELECT is better than if/then but I'm not sure you'll see significant performance gains in a query like this.

Comment: If I can get a large performance gain out of this (i.e. one option is noticeably slower) I would prefer that. If not, best practice is ok. This is more for my learning, need to understand pros/cons of different approaches.